# Python requests isn't fully loading the site

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.9

## **The Issue**

Currently using `requests` and `beautifulsoup4` library.
I am trying to scrape the title of a website
The issue is: the response I am getting from `s.get()` doesn't contain the right title
Title I get in my browser: `"Crate Battles :: bandit.camp - The true immersive Rust gaming experience"`
Title I get from `s.get()`: `"bandit.camp - The true immersive Rust gaming experience"`

## **First Attempt**

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://bandit.camp/crate-battles'

s = requests.Session()
html = s.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

elements = soup.find_all('title')

for element in elements:
    print(element)

# <title>bandit.camp - The true immersive Rust gaming experience</title>
```

## **Second Attempt**

I then tried to wait 5 seconds before scraping the page. However it returns the same title

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

url = 'https://bandit.camp/crate-battles'

s = requests.Session()
s.get(url)
sleep(5)
html = s.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

elements = soup.find_all('title')

for element in elements:
    print(element)

# <title>bandit.camp - The true immersive Rust gaming experience</title>
```

Comment: No matter how long you set it to `sleep`, [all you'll get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1oMx.png) with `requests...get(url).text` is the [source html](https://medium.com/@codebyamir/ca52f06110a0) from `url`, which you can check on your browser by [previewing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHbNA.png) the first request in the [network logs](https://support.happyfox.com/kb/article/882-accessing-the-browser-console-and-network-logs/) after refreshing or by [adding `view-source:`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtnM2.png) before the link in the address bar.

Comment: For [dynamic sites](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_web_scraping/python_web_scraping_dynamic_websites.htm) like these, you might want something that supports JavaScript (neither requests not bs4 does) like [selenium](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/2f8ad15efe25)  or [`HTMLSession`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks, I started using selenium.

Comment: You're going to have a tough time getting anything from this site. Its contents, as already stated by others, is highly dynamic and alsmo all of it is in [Wasm](https://webassembly.org/).